# In C/C++, is there a directive similar to #ifndef for typedefs?

Tags: c++, c

If I want to define a value only if it is not defined, I do something like this :

```
#ifndef THING
#define THING OTHER_THING
#endif
```

What if `THING` is a `typedef`'d identifier, and not defined? I would like to do something like this:

```
#ifntypedef thing_type
typedef uint32_t thing_type
#endif
```

The issue arose because I wanted to check to see if an external library has already defined the `boolean` type, but I'd be open to hearing a more general solution.

Comment: @ZachRattner:
Just for your information,
if your compiler MSVC, `__if_not_exists` is available in C++.
For example, a code like
`__if_not_exists( thing_type ) { typedef uint32_t thing_type; }`
is possible.

Comment: In C11 and C++ you are allowed to re-typedef a typedef to the same thing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No there is no such facility in C++ at preprocessing stage. At the max can do is

```
#ifndef thing_type
#define thing_type uint32_t 
#endif
```

Though this is not a good coding practice and I don't suggest it.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I prefer when people tell me what is wrong with an answer rather than just a downvote. The problem with this approach is that `typedef` creates a real alias to the type, while a macro is *only* text substitution. In the example it does not matter, but the semantics of `void foo( const X x )` are very different depending on whether `X` is a typedef or the macro above: `typedef int* X` will make the function `void foo( int * const )`, while `#define X int*` will make it `void foo( int const * )` (darn `const` on the leftmost side!)

Comment: defines != typedefs. Actually, defines < typedefs. Bad coding practice.

Comment: @DevSolar, I don't endorse this technique; this is one of the way.

Answer (score 27):

There is no such thing in the language, nor is it needed. Within a single project you should not have the same typedef alias referring to different types ever, as that is a violation of the ODR, and if you are going to create the same alias for the same type then just do it. The language allows you to perform the same typedef as many times as you wish and will usually catch that particular ODR (within the same translation unit):

```
typedef int myint;
typedef int myint;       // OK: myint is still an alias to int
//typedef double myint;  // Error: myint already defined as alias to int
```

If what you are intending to do is implementing a piece of functionality for different types by using a typedef to determine which to use, then you should be looking at templates rather than typedefs.

Comment: N.B.:  FYI for C it is not valid to declare a typedef more than once, even if they both alias the same type.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8367810/816536

Comment: Not true. When writing libraries this can easily come up. What do you use in a header file when a function should return a boolean? If your library is used in an X project, then X already defines BOOL. If you use your library in another project, there may be a different, and totally incompatible definition of Bool.

Comment: @GregA.Woods C11 added this capability to C; the answer you linked to only answers for C99

Comment: This feature would be useful for a project that should work with C89 and C99 compilers across different platforms without code changes, and wants some of the typedefs added in C99, such as uintmax_t.  A header file could emulate the typedef if it isn't already available.

Answer (score 23):

C++ does not provide any mechanism for code to test presence of `typedef`, the best you can have is something like this:

```
#ifndef THING_TYPE_DEFINED
#define THING_TYPE_DEFINED
typedef uint32_t thing_type 
#endif
```

**EDIT:**
<sup>As @David, is correct in his comment, this answers the *how?* part but importantly misses the *why?* It can be done in the way above, If you want to do it et all, but important it you probably don't need to do it anyways, @David's answer & comment explains the details, and I think that answers the question correctly.</sup>

Comment: That is *ugly* and *useless*. The important question is not how to do this, but *why would you do it?* And the answer is you *shouldn't*. A typedef can be redefined as many times as you wish (provided that it always aliases the same type) within the same translation unit so that is not a problem. Defining it to alias different types in different translation units of the same program is a violation of the ODR, so you don't want that either. The best you can get is *nothing* if the alias is always the same, or *hiding* an error at compile time depending on what was included before.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I agree, I think I missed out one `why?` and just jumped on to the `how?` part of it. I am going to add a note on the same.

Answer (score 7):

Preprocessor directives (like `#define`) are crude text replacement tools, which know nothing about the programming language, so they can't act on any language-level definitions.

There are two approaches to making sure a type is only defined once:

- Structure the code so that each definition has its place, and there's no need for multiple definitions
- `#define` a preprocessor macro alongside the type, and use `#ifndef` to check for the macro definition before defining the type.

The first option will generally lead to more maintainable code. The second could cause subtle bugs, if you accidentally end up with different definitions of the type within one program.

Answer (score 2):

As other have already said, there are no such thing, but if you try to create an alias to different type, you'll get a compilation error :

```
typedef int myInt;
typedef int myInt;    // ok, same alias
typedef float myInt;  // error
```

However, there is a thing called [ctag](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html) for finding where a typedef is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of ctags.  This was new to me.

Answer (score 2):

This might not directly answer the question, but serve as a possible solution to your problem.

Why not try something like this?

```
#define DEFAULT_TYPE int // just for argument's sake
#ifndef MY_COOL_TYPE
     #define MY_COOL_TYPE DEFAULT_TYPE
#endif
typedef MY_COOL_TYPE My_Cool_Datatype_t;
```

Then if you want to customize the type, you can either define MY_COOL_TYPE somewhere above this (like in a "configure" header that is included at the top of this header) or pass it as a command line argument when compiling (as far as I know you can do this with GCC and LLVM, maybe others, too).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually  real PITA, because some  APIs or SDKs redefine commonly used things. I had issue that header files for a map processing software (GIS) were redefining TRUE and FALSE (generally used by windows SDK)keywords to integer literals instead of true and false keywords ( obviously, that can break SOMETHING). And yes, famous joke "#define true false" is relevant.

define would never feel a typedef or constant declared in C\C++ code because preprocessor doesn't analyze code, it only scans for # statements. And it modifies code prior to giving it to syntax analyzer. SO, in general, it's not possible.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkf423c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
 That one isn't portable so far, though there were known request to implement it  in GCC. I think, it also counts as "extension" in MSVC. It's a compiler statement, not a preprocessor statement, so it will not "feel" defined  macros, it would detect only typedefs outside of function body. "full type" there means that it will react on full definition, ignoring statements like "class SomeClass;". Use it at own risk.

Edit: apparently it also supported on MacOS now and by Intel comiler with -fms-dialect flag (AIX\Linux?)

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing like what you wanted. I have had your same problem with libraries that include their own`typedefs` for things like `bool`. It gets to be a problem when they just don't care about what you use for `bool` or if any other libs might be doing the same thing!!

So here's what I do. I edit the header file for the libs that do such things and find the `typedef bool` and add some code like this:

```
#ifdef USE_LIBNAME_BOOL
typedef unsigned char bool; // This is the lib's bool implementation
#else
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif
```

Notice that I included  if I didn't want to use the libs' own `bool typdef`. This means that you need C99 support or later.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before this is not included in the C++ standard, but you might be able to use autotools to get the same functionality.

You could use the [`ac_cxx_bool`](http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/ac-archive/ac_cxx_bool.html) macro to make sure bool is defined (or different routines for different datatypes).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was including stdbool.h. I know this doesn't solve the question of how to check if a typedef is already defined, but it does let me ensure that the boolean type is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. C and Unix have a history together, and there are a lot of Unix C typedefs not available on a non-POSIX platform such as Windows (shhh Cygwin people). You'll need to decide how to answer this question whenever you're trying to write C that's portable between these systems (shhhhh Cygwin people).

If cross-platform portability is what you need this for, then knowing the platform-specific *preprocessor macro* for the compilation target is sometimes helpful. E.g. windows has the `_WIN32` preprocessor macro defined - it's 1 whenever the compilation target is 32-bit ARM, 64-bit ARM, x86, or x64. But it's presence also informs us that we're on a Windows machine. This means that e.g. `ssize_t` won't be available (ssize_t, not size_t). So you might want to do something like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef long ssize_t;
#endif
```

By the way, people in this thread have commented about a similar pattern that is formally called a *guard*. You see it in header files (i.e. interfaces or ".h" files) a lot to prevent *multiple inclusion*. You'll hear about *header guards*.

```
/// @file poop.h

#ifndef POOP_H
#define POOP_H

void* poop(Poop* arg);

#endif
```

Now I can include the header file in the implementation file `poop.c` *and* some other file like `main.c`, and I know they will always compile successfully and without multiple inclusion, whether they are compiled together or individually, thanks to the header guards.

Salty seadogs write their header guards programmatically or with C++11 function-like macros. If you like books I recommend Jens Gustedt's "Modern C".

Answer (score -1):

It is not transparent but you can try to compile it one time without typedef (just using the alias), and see if it compiles or not.

Answer (score -1):

There is not such things.
It is possible to desactivate this duplicate_typedef compilator error.
"typedef name has already been declared (with same type)"

On a another hand, for some standardized typedef definition there is often a preprocessor macro defined like __bool_true_false_are_defined for bool that can be used.