# redefinition of typedef

Tags: c, gcc, typedef

*I am possibly doing this incorrectly and this is much a question about why it works in one compiler and not the other.*

I have a large C application, and I am trying to follow the style of not including header files from within other header files. Instead, using forward declarations; thus I am trying the following.

```
// in A.h
typedef struct A_ A;
typedef struct B_ B;
struct A_ {
    double a;
    B *b;
};

// in B.h
typedef struct B_ B;
struct B_ {
    int c;
};

// in C.h
typedef struct A_ A;
typedef struct B_ B;
void function_do_something(A*, B*);

// in C.c
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
void function_do_something(A* a, B* b) {
    ...
}
```

This paradigm compiles and runs in Ubuntu 11.10 gcc -- but it gives compiler erros in OpenSUSE gcc that say "redefinition of typedef".

I have been doing my development in Ubunutu and so hadn't realised that this paradigm might be incorrect. Is it just that this is plain wrong and Ubuntu's gcc is being too nice?

Comment: @Charles sorry, C.c should also include A.h and B.h so that it knows about the struct contents

Comment: THIS is why i want to replace C preprocessor with php, or any other scripting language. This is absurd. You can't even conditionally typedef(unless you balance every typedef with a macro to indicate the typedef has been set)!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was surprised by this because I'm fairly sure that redeclaring the same typedef in the same scope is legal in C++, but apparently it is not legal in C prior to the 2011 standard.

First, typedef names have no linkage:

ISO/IEC 9899:1999 + TC3 6.2.2/6 (Linkages of identifiers):

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than
> an object or a function [...]

and 6.7/3 (Declarations):

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier
> (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except
> for tags as specified in 6.7.2.3.

So you need to ensure that each typedef declaration appears only once at file scope in each translation unit.

The 2011 C standard allows redeclaration of typedef names. 6.7 3 says:

> … a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type;…

Comment: So does this mean that I am better off just including headers within headers so that the include guards take care of it? Out using struct without typedef?

Comment: @BrT: Yes, I think so. It slightly depends on your objectives. If you only need to use the name of the typedef as a reference to an incomplete type then you can use a seperate header with the typedef declarationas in @Potatoswatter's answer. If you were just using the typedefs as an alternative to `#include` and there's no particular cost to defining the complete struct in each TU, then you may as well keep the `#include` and optionally keep the typedef declaration with the definition of the type for consistency.

Comment: In the program I'm now making with C9 it seems you cannot include a header with a typedef more than once without errors.

Comment: Since C11 (8 months before this answer!) it is allowed to re-define a typedef to the same thing. An exception was added to 6.7/3 for this case

Comment: I think what @M.M said needs to be included in this answer. Otherwise, it's misleading.

Comment: @M.M This is a big pain for existing code bases. For those looking, -std=c11 is your answer.

Answer (score 6):

One piece of the idiom is missing. The forward declarations are independent from the definitions, so they should be in a separate header file.

```
// a_fwd.h

#ifndef A_FWD_H
#define A_FWD_H

typedef struct A_ A;

#endif

// a.h

#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "a_fwd.h"

struct A_ {
};

#endif
```

Now it's always safe to include any headers in any order.

---

It is illegal to have two definitions of anything. A typedef is a definition, not just a declaration, so the one compiler was being quite lax to allow the redundancy.

Comment: Regarding your last statement, I thought you could only have _definitions_ of objects and functions in C and that a typedef declaration was a declaration that introduced a new name for an existing type?

Comment: @CharlesBailey C99, §6.7/5: "A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that: … for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the identifier."

Comment: Put declarations outside the guard token, and definitions inside.

Comment: @Calmarius: *Never put anything outside the `#ifndef … #endif` block*, if that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a matter of style I would put the typedef after the struct. i.e.:

```
struct B_ {
    int c;
};
typedef struct B_ B;
```

That way you are saying: "here is B_ and now I want to refer to it as B". It could be that the other way around fools something in the compiler.

Comment: No, the order makes no difference.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting the typedef first. Putting it first says "if you see `B`, it's actually `struct B`". It's used all over the place in plan 9, and is really nice for linked lists, allowing `typedef struct A A; struct A {int data; A *next};`

Answer (score 1):

The ubuntu compiler is being overly soft; you can't typedef the same thing twice. In the style you refer to, the ordering of the includes is important, and is usually mentioned as a comment in the header file, or in the documentation. In this case, you would have:

```
//A.h
typedef struct A A;
struct A {
    double a;
    B* b;
};

// B.h
typedef struct B B;
struct B {
    int c;
};

// C.h
void function_do_something(A*, B*);

// C.c
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
#include "C.h"

void function_do_something(A* a, B* b){ ... }
```

You might note that this will get messy in the case of cyclic dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining A and B by writing the same statement in several header files. One solution would be to drop the `typedef` of A and B from the A.h and B.h and use your C.h as it is.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, you cannot redefine types in C. This error mostly indicates that there might be looped includes or other logic flaw. To avoid this, the best practice is to lock include files i.e.

```
#ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__

// Your code goes here

#endif
```

This way unnecessary includes will be omitted by this lock.
In your example you would need to include B in A and A in C. Including B in C would have no effect and would satisfy the compiler

Comment: OP is specifically not including headers within headers. That makes include guards unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't put it I'm the question, but all headers have guards already.

Comment: Then it's more appropriate to use extern declarations

Answer (score -2):

**You are defining multiple times the same thing.**

You can spread it across multiple header files just have to make sure that there is some B seen before struct _A is defined.

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _B B;
typedef struct _A A;

struct _A {
    double a;
    B *b;
};

struct _B {
    int c;
};

void function_do_something(A* a, B* b)
{
    printf("a->a (%f) b->c (%d)\n", a->a, b->c);
}

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;

  a.a = 3.4;
  b.c = 34;

  function_do_something(&a, &b);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
> ./x
a->a (3.400000) b->c (34)
```

**EDIT**: updated for C

**EDIT 2**: spread into multiple header files

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

struct _B {
    int c;
};

#endif
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

typedef struct _B B;

struct _A {
    double a;
    B *b;
};

typedef struct _A A;

#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

void function_do_something(A* a, B* b)
{
    printf("a->a (%f) b->c (%d)\n", a->a, b->c);
}

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;

  a.a = 3.4;
  b.c = 34; 

  function_do_something(&a, &b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is C so no `std::cout` etc.

Comment: This will most certainly not work in C. You will have to use typedef otherwise you cannot use A & B as you have in the code

Comment: How would the multiple file solution work if function_do_something had to be in its own file?  Our if A and B were also used in another function in another file?