# Two structs in different header files, both using the other

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I've already gone through a bunch of threads on hear and a bunch of others I found on Google.  I still can't seem to get this right.

```
//Room.h
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include "Door.h"

typedef struct {
   Door* doors[3];

} Room;

#endif

//Door.h
#ifndef DOOR_H
#define DOOR_H

#include "Room.h"

typedef struct {
   Room* room1;
   Room* room2;
} Door;

//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Room.h"
int main() { ... }
```

I already tried adding this to the top of Door.h

```
typedef struct Room room1;
//typedef struct Room* room1;
//typedef stuct Room;
//typedef struct Room*;
```

All gave me this error:

"unknown type name ‘Room’"

I want to keep these structs separate header files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C-way of struct reference:

room.h

```
typedef struct Room_s {
  struct Door_s * doors[3];
} Room_t;
```

door.h

```
typedef struct Door_s {
  struct Room_s *room1;
  struct Room_s *room2;
} Door_t;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Honestly,  I feel like a noob now for not trying this.  I had the same issue before, except I was trying to use a struct within its self, and I did exactly this and it worked...

Comment: why does this solve it? one struct will still be declared before the other?

Answer (score 8):

Try it like this:

```
typedef struct Room Room;
typedef struct Door Door;

struct Room{
   Door* doors[3];
};

struct Door{
   Room* room1;
   Room* room2;
};
```

---

The first two lines are the type declarations that will allow them to reference each other.

It won't matter how you separate these in the header files as long as the first two lines come first.

---

In your case, they can be split as follows:

**room.h**

```
typedef struct Door Door;

struct Room{
   Door* doors[3];
};
```

**door.h**

```
typedef struct Room Room;

struct Door{
   Room* room1;
   Room* room2;
};
```

Comment: This didn't work.  They are in two separate header files by the way.  I just threw in a string variable to see if I could access it from the other struct, but it was a no go.

Comment: The actual `struct` definitions shouldn't use `typedef` to avoid `typedef` redefinition errors.

Comment: @CoolJoe I edited in how you could separate them into headers. But I'm not understanding the second problem that you're having.

Comment: In the Rooms struct I now have a string char*t.

In my main, I created a new room with room.t = "test";

In my door.h file i have this function: void printthis(Room* room) { printf("%s", room.t);

it's giving me this error:

"request for member ‘t’ in something not a structure or union"

Comment: @jamesdlin I've never actually had problems with this approach. In all the compilers that I use, what I have here works. Unless they all happen to allow it by extension.

Comment: @CoolJoe That should have nothing to do with the `struct` definitions. It's something else. Are you declaring that member properly?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hAxjTUud

exactly what I have

edit: I noticed I had a '.' instead of a '->' let me see if I can get it working..?

Comment: Oh, your `room2.t` should be `room2->t`. `room2` is a pointer in that function.

Comment: damn, I was hoping I would edit my post before anyone noticed so I didn't look like a dunce. :P

Comment: I'm getting a "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" error.

Checking google and my code right now.  Do you see anything else wrong?  It's probably when I'm declaring the struct in main..?

Comment: `typedef struct Foo Foo; typedef struct Foo { int x; } Foo;` fails using `gcc -g -Wall` (gcc 4.3.3).  At any rate, the duplicate `typedef` is pointless, so why bother having it? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367646/redefinition-of-typedef

Comment: @Cool Joe In that case, you need to include `Room.h` before you include `Door.h`.

Comment: GOT IT, thanks. :]

I was using make, and it wasn't compiling my header files.

Comment: @jamesdlin Hang on a sec. while I pull up another compiler... You're probably right.

Comment: @jamesdlin Indeed you are correct. The reason why it "worked" for me on all compilers was because I was compiling for C++. I've fixed my answer for a C working version without the duplicate `typedef`s.

Comment: Note that this approach puts the typedef for Door into room.h and the typedef for Room into door.h. That's a maintenance hell waiting to happen, especially if you have more of these.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating anonymous structs and typedefing them, give the structs particular names as below:

#### common.h

```
typedef struct Door_ Door;
typedef struct Room_ Room;
```

#### room.h

```
#include "common.h"

struct Room_ {
  Door* doors[3];
};
```

#### door.h

```
#include "common.h"

struct Door_ {
  Room *room1;
  Room *room2;
};
```

Although, if you were planning to have `room.h` and `door.h` always used together, I'd just make one file to put all the definitions in.

Comment: This just seams odd.  I will have other structs that do the same thing with each other and I don't want to have "common1.h", "common2.h", etc.. and I also want these to all be in their own header files.  

edit: I see what you mean with putting all the definitions into one file, even if they all don't use each other.  Still seams like there is another way...

Comment: I just got around to testing this, and indeed it also works. +1