# Why can't I complete a typedef name of array type?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer

The C standard states (§6.2.5 p22):

> An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type. It is completed,
>   for an identifier of that type, by specifying the size in a later
>   declaration (with internal or external linkage).

And it works fine as far as variable declarations are concerned:

```
int a[];
int a[2]; //OK
```

But when we add `typedef` before those declarations the compiler complains (I also changed the name):

```
typedef int t[];
typedef int t[2]; //redefinition with different type
```

It doesn't complain however when we are completing a typedef to incomplete structure instead:

```
typedef struct t t1;
typedef struct t { int m; } t1; //OK
```

Possible use case of an incomplete typedef of array could be something like this:

```
int main(int n, char **pp)
{
    typedef int t1[][200];
    typedef struct t { t1 *m; int m1; } t0;
    typedef int t1[sizeof (t0)][200];
}
```

In the above example I would like to declare a pointer to array inside a structure with number of elements equal to the structure size. Yes I could use a structure instead of array but why should I when the above option is potentially available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redefinition of typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367646/redefinition-of-typedef).

Comment: Please limit your editing. I'm trying to write an answer, and I don't want to deal with the reorganisation of your examples.

Answer (score 4):

`typedef int t[2];` is not allowed because of the constraint 6.7/3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except that:
>
> - a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type;

However `int[]` and `int[2]` are not the same type, so this "except" doesn't apply, and so the code violates the constraint.

---

Regarding your first quote: Although 6.2.5/22 says that an incomplete type can be completed,  it doesn't follow that any attempted completion is automatically legal. The attempted completion must also comply with all the other rules of the language, and in this case it does not comply with 6.7/3.

The `int a[]; int a[2];` example is OK (under 6.7/3) because `a` has linkage; and in the `typedef struct t t1;` , `struct t` is still the same type before and after its completion.

Answer (score 0):

From [6.2.5p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p1), we can see a definition of the terms *complete* and *incomplete*:

> At various points within a translation unit an object type may be incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information).

Thus, when we talk about a *type* being incomplete, we're really talking about the size of *objects of that type* being indeterminate. We can't talk about "incomplete types" without declaring an object of that type.

In your first example, the size of `a` is determinate as you've completed the definition *for the object* using the second declaration.

In your second example, no declaration *for an object* is made. Once the declaration is made, e.g. `t x = { 1, 2 };`, it becomes clear that the type *isn't* incomplete.

In your third example, you're not actually completing the type alias; you're completing the `struct` definition. You might as well have written:

```
typedef struct t t1;
struct t { int m; };
```

---

We can see further support for the redefinition of `struct` tags, and the exclusion of the VLA redefinition in [6.7p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p3):

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except that:
>
> - a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type;
> - tags may be redeclared as specified in 6.7.2.3.

Comment: "We can't talk about "incomplete types" without declaring an object of that type."  - there are function parameters too, e.g. `void f( int (*p)[] );`  , `*p` has incomplete type. Also `void` is an incomplete type and you cannot declare objects of void.

Comment: @M.M "there are function parameters too, e.g. `void f( int (*p)[] );`, `*p` has incomplete type"; I never claimed you *can't declare* an object that has an incomplete type. "Also `void` is an incomplete type and you cannot declare objects of `void`"; Again, I never claimed you *could complete* the `void` type. [6.2.5p19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19) is fairly clear about that. I suggest clarifying the distinction between *declaration* and *completion*...

Comment: We're talking about `void` now , so "we can't talk about incomplete types" is clearly false.  Maybe re-word that sentence, I'm not sure what you are trying to say there.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion.** This discussion was becoming (1) extended and (2) unproductive. I have cleaned it up. Everyone please refrain from further comments unless they add something new and are *relevant to the question.*